# How do I disable a input type button when a input type text in less than 0 or bigger than 24?

Tags: javascript, html, css, button

I need to make a points calculator that the user will input the number of objects and the site will tell how much points they worth. so far i manage to do that, but i can't think of any way of stopping the user to more objects than there are. Here is the code:

```
 <form>
 <input type="text" name="ob1" size="3" value="0/24" onClick="this.value='';" /> object      <input type="text" name="ob2" size="3" value="0/24" onClick="this.value='';" />
 <br>
 <input type="button" value="Calculate Points" onClick="document.getElementById('calcu').innerHTML='Supply points are ' + (ab1.value*5) +'. Tower points are '+(ab2.value*10)+'.'" name="clc"></form>
 <div id="calcu"></div>
```

Comment: Is that really all your code?

Comment: He missed the code tag, i edited his post and added it.

Answer (score 0):

jsFiddle( http://jsfiddle.net/gP7SP/15/ )

I'm going on a few assumptions, but here you go:

```
<form>
    Supply:<input type="text" id="supply" name="ob1" size="3" value="0/24" onClick="this.value='';" />
    Tower:<input type="text" id="tower" name="ob2" size="3" value="0/24" onClick="this.value='';" />
    <br/>
    <input type="button" value="Calculate Points" onClick="calculate()" name="clc">
</form>

<div id="calcu"></div>

<script type="text/javascript">
    function calculate()
    {
        // Retrieve the supply and tower values
        var supply = parseInt( document.getElementById("supply").value );
        var tower = parseInt( document.getElementById("tower").value );

        // Make sure supply is less than 24
        if ( supply > 24 )
        {
            alert( "Supply cannot be greater than 24" );
        }
        // Make sure tower is less than 24    
        else if ( tower > 24 )
        {
            alert( "Tower cannot be greater than 24" );
        }
        else
        {
            // Computer new values
            supply = supply * 5;
            tower = tower * 10;

            // Write the values to the calcu div
            document.getElementById("calcu").innerHTML = "Supply points: " + supply + ", Tower points: " + tower;
        }
    }
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to disable the textbox, just trigger an alert as an error message.

Something along the lines of:

```
var obj1 = document.forms["form_name"]["obj1"].value;
if (obj1 < 0 || obj1 > 24) {
   alert("Error message");
   return false;
}
```

Comment: alert is bad practice - blocks the whole browser.